# Npgsql / EF 6 - json column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, npgsql, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to create a migration with a JSON column. Here's what I tried:

```
    [Column(TypeName = "Jsonb")]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "Json")]
    public string Data { get; set; }

    modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().Property(p => p.Data).HasColumnType("Json");

    modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().Property(p => p.Data).HasColumnType("Jsonb");
```

Nothing works at all, here's the exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, String name)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(Tuple`2 pm)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(IEnumerable`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(IList`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntityType entityType, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection`1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
>      at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_Local()
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.get_Local()
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilderExtensions.RegisterUserAccountChildTablesForDelete[TKey,TAccount,TUserClaim,TLinkedAccount,TLinkedAccountClaim,TPasswordResetSecret,TTwoFactorAuthToken,TUserCertificate](DbContext ctx) in c:\ballen\github\brockallen\BrockAllen.MembershipReboot\src\BrockAllen.MembershipReboot.Ef\DbModelBuilderExtensions.cs:line 26

Here's my config:

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="EntityFramework6.Npgsql" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Npgsql" version="3.1.6" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is totally doable, but requires modifying the generated migration rather than annotating your model or using fluent configuration.  In your generated migration, alter the declaration of the `data` column to use `storeType` and `defaultValueSql` arguments:

```
data = c.String(nullable: false, storeType: "jsonb", defaultValueSql: "'{}'::jsonb")
```

I can confirm this works for Npgsql 3.1.7 with EntityFramework6.Npgsql 3.1.1, and will save and load applicable entities without issue.  Can't vouch for earlier versions.